# RecyclerView in multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have an app using a TabLayout, each Tab is represented with a fragment and 3 of my tab (hence fragments) are using RecyclerView with custom adapters.

My problem is the following:

- I start a **background job in** **Tab1** (eg: downloading a file) and refresh a specific item from my `RecyclerView` with `notifyItemChanged(int position)`
- Then `onBindViewHolder` is automatically called and the layout of the item is refreshed as expected
- HOWEVER, if I switch to another tab containing another `RecyclerView` (eg: Tab2)
- Then when I come back to Tab1 the layout of the item being downloaded is not refreshed because `notifyItemChanged(int position)` **doesn't trigger a call to** `onBindViewHolder` anymore

PS: Yes the Tab1 is still on the stack (I hold a strong reference to it in my PagerAdapter).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Need to see some code. How do you obtain "hard reference" to fragment? If you have more than 2 tabs you might experience views being destroyed when swapping between tabs, are you sure it's not happening?

Comment: I have a fixed number of tabs (4) that are created in the activity holding them: that is where the strong reference is from.


Yes I'm sure that swapping between tabs doesn't destroy the fragments because their onDestroy method is never called.

Comment: Have you checked if fragment's View is destroyed? (`onDestroyView`)

Comment: I didn't think of onDestroyView... Good spot thanks!